# Why does Symfony Guard fire 'security.interactive_login' event on every request?

Tags: symfony, symfony-3.2

I have a Symfony 3.2 application which exposes a REST API and uses Json Web Tokens (JWT) for authentication. I recently switched to using Symfony's Guard component. Now my `security.yml` contains a firewall config section as follows (I'm using the Lexik JWT bundle 2.4.0, but this shouldn't matter):

```
firewalls:
    # ...
    api:
        pattern:   ^/api
        stateless: true
        guard:
            authenticators:
               - lexik_jwt_authentication.jwt_token_authenticator
```

Since I did this switch, I notice that *every* request is handled as if the user just logged in, i.e. a `security.interactive_login` event is fired. 
In the docs (http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/security/authentication.html#authentication-events) it states:

> The security.interactive_login event is triggered after a user has actively
>   logged into your website. It is important to distinguish this action from
>   non-interactive authentication methods, such as:
>      authentication based on a "remember me" cookie,
>      authentication based on your session,
>      authentication using a HTTP basic or HTTP digest header.
>   You could listen on the security.interactive_login event, for example, in
>   order to give your user a welcome flash message every time they log in.

So I definitely don't expect this event for every request - I'd rather expect to get the `security.authentication.success` event on every request, as pointed out in the docs.

However, Symfony's `GuardAuthenticatorHandler` class dispatches the `security.interactive_login` event in its `authenticateWithToken` method, and this method is called by the `GuardAuthenticationListener` on every request.
Is that a bug in Symfony, a misunderstanding on my side, or due to incorrect configuration?

(This is not a philosophical question - in my case it leads to the concrete problem that the last login time of the user is updated on every request, which does not make sense.)

Comment: have you found a solution ? I have the exact same problem, and I want a clean solution not any hack mention bellow...

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't find a proper solution.

Answer (score 1):

You should change this

```
        stateless: false
```

Comment: Can you elaborate why? To me it sounds like JWT authenticated requests are used to have a stateless conversation.

Comment: This is explained here http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/api_key_authentication.html#storing-authentication-in-the-session if you set stateless true then you don't store the authentication in the session and you are expected to authenticate every time.

Answer (score 1):

I've come across your issue, because I've exactly the same problem. My workaround is to add a attribute in the request object, right before return true in the supports method of the guard.

Example:

```
public function supports(Request $request)
{
    ...

    $request->attributes->set('is_interactive_login', true);

    return true;
}
```

With this information you can check if it was a interactive login in the event listener

Example:

```
public function onLoginSuccess(InteractiveLoginEvent $event)
{
    $request = $event->getRequest();
    if ($request->attributes->get('is_interactive_login', false)) {
        // do whatever you need todo on interactive login
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Better to subscribe to `Events::JWT_CREATED` event, as it's fired after authentication with credentials has been passed.

Example:

```
<?php

namespace App\Event\Subscriber;

use App\Entity\User\User;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Lexik\Bundle\JWTAuthenticationBundle\Event\JWTCreatedEvent;
use Lexik\Bundle\JWTAuthenticationBundle\Events;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;

class AuthenticationSuccessSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    /**
     * @var EntityManager
     */
    private $em;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            Events::JWT_CREATED => 'onInteractiveLogin',
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @param JWTCreatedEvent $event
     *
     * @throws \Doctrine\ORM\ORMException
     * @throws \Doctrine\ORM\OptimisticLockException
     */
    public function onInteractiveLogin(JWTCreatedEvent $event)
    {
        /** @var User $user */
        $user = $event->getUser();
        $user->setLastLoginAt(new \DateTime());
        $user->resetFailedLogins();
        $this->em->flush($user);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've faced with same trouble. In my case I use Guard authentication for API requests. So I definitely don't like updating user's last_login after any API request.

INTERACTIVE_LOGIN event is dispatched from [here](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/d9bcfc316a149637b3fe1637c430bdf72f236d46/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Guard/GuardAuthenticatorHandler.php#L65).

So my dirty hack is to add this definition to the `services` section of app's config:

```
security.authentication.guard_handler:
        class: Symfony\Component\Security\Guard\GuardAuthenticatorHandler
        arguments:
            $eventDispatcher: ~
```

## Warning

Obvious drawback of this approach is that you <strike>broke</strike> change handler for all your app's guards.